# iPhone: How to programmatically create a json file and insert the data obtained from my Sqlite database into it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, json, ios4

I want to get data from my Sqlite database and put it into this JSON file.

How can I create a json file and insert the data obtained from my database into the JSON file?

I want data in JSON file in this format:

```
{

"data": [
    {
        "data": [
            null,
            null,
            30,
            45,
            69,
            70,
            65
        ],
        "title": "title5" 
    },
    {
        "data": [
            null,
            5,
            10,
            15,
            22,
            30 
        ],
        "title": "title4" 
    },
    {
        "data": [
            40,
            55,
        ],
        "title": "title3" 
    },
    {
          "data": [
              null,
            89,
            90,
            85
        ],
        "title": "title2" 
    },
    {
        "data": [
            66,
            77,
            55,
            33,
            50,
            -6,
            -8
        ],
        "title": "title1" 
    } 
],
 "x_labels": [
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12
]
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Json is the parsing method you have to put the data into the text file from the databse in your desire format than you can use the json parsing to parse  the local file's  json data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Obj C object reading data from your sqlite database. Say

```
@interface Data:NSObject {
  NSArray *data;
  NSString *title;
}

NSArray *dataArray; // array of data filled with all Data object read from database.
```

1. Use [JSON Framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) to convert all data to JSON string. Notice that for the Data object, you have to override the `proxyForJson` method, since its a user defined object.

You can make a JSON string from an object ,

```
SBJsonWriter *writer = [SBJsonWriter new];
NSString *jsonString = [writer stringWithObject:dataArray];
[writer release];
```

I am not sure if it works directly for array, if not, encapsulate your dataArray in anotherObject, and send that object to this JSON writer.

Write the JSON string to a file.

```
 [jsonString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
             error:nil]
```

Comment: I think you are very close to the answer. Can you please provide a dataArray and show how it creates file out of it?

Comment: I also have a doubt on how to take each of my dataset with same key "data" and "title"? I suppose it overwrites the values when I try to fetch the data from the database into my dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a json output what you can do is first get the sqlite data in some array or plist or dictionary etc, then use the function JSONRepresentation to display the JSON output for the same, here's a sample code that might help you

```
-(void)create_Json
{
    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ravi",@"Riki",@"Faisal",@"Sanjay", nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:arr forKey:@"Friends"];

    NSLog(@"JSON representation for dictionary is %@",[dict JSONRepresentation]);

}
```

Make sure that you are importing the JSON libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I want it in a JSON file with a .json extension in my Main Bundle. I don't just want to display it.  How can I create a json file out of it?

Comment: @Parth: so let me get this you want the json file to be created in your main bundle is that so and even if it is the case then you cannot do that because the iPhone bundle has only read only access. You may use the document directory for doing this kind of stuff, like you create a json output and create a file with the .json extension in the document directory file. Hope this helps